# A-star search in numpy or python

Tags: python, numpy, a-star

i tried searching stackoverflow for the tags `[a-star] [and] [python]` and `[a-star] [and] [numpy]`, but nothing. i also googled it but whether due to the tokenizing or its existence, i got nothing.

it's not much harder than your coding-interview tree traversals to implement. but, it would be nice to have a correct efficient implementation for everyone.

does numpy have A*?

Comment: The implication of A star would depend on the situation. Do you need the algorithm on a grid? On a two dimensional plane? A multidimensional plane? 

To my knowledge numpy does not have an A* algorithm.

Comment: well, when discrete, those are all graphs. A* works on any graph (i.e. any data structure with a `.next()`. grids call it neighbors, trees call it children, etc.

Comment: Try this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390458/how-to-structure-an-adjacency-list-for-this-a-program

Comment: Question asked long time ago, but I ran into it, and was expecting an answer. Since it didn't provide any, I eventually found an answer someplace else. There is an A* implementation in python [here](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/implementation.html#sec-1-4)

Answer (score 3):

Numpy doesn't have A*, but NetworkX has. See https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.astar.astar_path.html .

Comment: Seconded; a graph library would be the best place to go looking for this kind of functionality

Answer (score 3):

Because your question specifies `numpy` OR `python`: There is at least [one astar solver in python available on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astar).

Also there seems to be a few options on GitHub, one of which [leverages numpy and c++ (hopefully efficiently)](https://github.com/hjweide/a-star).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no A* search in Numpy.

Answer (score -1):

Gamedev libraries are providing their implementations as well. For example, `libtcod` (a roguelike engine) has it [here](http://roguecentral.org/doryen/data/libtcod/doc/1.5.2/html2/path_init.html?c=false&cpp=false&cs=false&py=false&lua=false), but it is only useful for `libtcod`'s own grid.

General-purpose A* "for everyone" is impossible because there is just too many things it can be applied to. All sorts of graphs, grids, planes, and all of them can be implemented in a dozen ways with dozen APIs each.